# Creating web application using ruby only without using any framework

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I have to develop an application in Ruby without using any framework (Rails, sinatra, Shoes n all). Is there any way that we can create some HTML pages, Css files and call ruby script on a click of a button. Is there any method to do it.

Comment: Since all those frameworks are written in Ruby, of course you can do it without using them as long as you implement similar functions by yourself.

Comment: That is too value a question to be asked on this site. What particular function with what particular specification do you want to implement?

Comment: @sawa Just want to create a login page and provide some information. But i want to know how can i call ruby script from html?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to do this? Frameworks take away so much of the hard work for you. If you want something extremely lightweight, use Rack.

Everything you need should be there, or dig into the source code at https://github.com/rack/rack to get started